# How to select rows in a dataframe based on a string customers list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a **first** dataframe containing bills and in this dataframe a column named `contents` contains customers names inside a no formatted / standardized string, like this :

```
   NUMBIL      DATE                           CONTENTS AMOUNT
0     858  01/01/23                    Billed to HENRY    25$
1     863  01/01/23                             VIKTOR    96$
2     870  01/01/23                     Regard to ALEX    13$
3     871  07/01/23                           MARK 01*    96$
4     872  07/01/23  To charge SAMANTHA every Thursday    96$
5     880  08/01/23                     VIKTOR LECOMTE    13$
6     881  08/01/23                               ****    13$
```

I have a **second** dataframe consisting of a short list of customers names, like this :

```
     NUMBIL
0    VIKTOR
1      ALEX
2  SAMANTHA
```

**What I would like to do**

Based on customers list identify rows in first dataframe that do not contain customers names in `CONTENTS` column.

In our case resulting dataframe would be :

```
   NUMBIL      DATE         CONTENTS AMOUNT
0     858  01/01/23  Billed to HENRY    25$
3     871  07/01/23         MARK 01*    96$
6     881  08/01/23             ****    13$
```

I have already found a possible solution to my problem, but I think this topic could be useful to the community, and I would like to know the uniqueness way you would handle this ?

**Dataframe to start with**

```py
import pandas as pd

fct = pd.DataFrame({'NUMBIL':[858, 863, 870, 871, 872, 880, 881],
                   'DATE':['01/01/23', '01/01/23', '01/01/23', '07/01/23', '07/01/23', '08/01/23', '08/01/23'],
                   'CONTENTS':['Billed to HENRY', 'VIKTOR', 'Regard to ALEX', 'MARK 01*', 
                               'To charge SAMANTHA every Thursday', 'VIKTOR LECOMTE', '****'],
                   'AMOUNT':['25$', '96$', '13$', '96$', '96$', '13$', '13$'],
                   })

cust = pd.DataFrame({'CUSTOMERS':['VIKTOR', 'ALEX', 'SAMANTHA'],
                   })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can craft a regex for [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and invert its output (`~`) for [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
import re

pattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, cust['CUSTOMERS']))

out = fct[~fct['CONTENTS'].str.contains(pattern)]
```

If you only want to match full words (e.g., `SAM` wouldn't match `SAMANTHA`), add word boundaries (`\b`):

```
out = fct[~fct['CONTENTS'].str.contains(fr'\b(?:{pattern})\b')]
```

Output:

```
   NUMBIL      DATE         CONTENTS AMOUNT
0     858  01/01/23  Billed to HENRY    25$
3     871  07/01/23         MARK 01*    96$
6     881  08/01/23             ****    13$
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Set theory

This would be much faster when you have large number of customers to test against

```
s = set(cust['CUSTOMERS'])
fct[fct['CONTENTS'].map(lambda c: s.isdisjoint(c.split()))]
```

Result

```
   NUMBIL      DATE         CONTENTS AMOUNT
0     858  01/01/23  Billed to HENRY    25$
3     871  07/01/23         MARK 01*    96$
6     881  08/01/23             ****    13$
```

Comment: It's true that sets can be faster (not *much* faster for reasonable input), but a regex approach is not slow (maximum a few milliseconds for 1M rows and several thousands of customers), on the other side sets are limited to full words, make it harder to handle case or dangling punctuation. I love sets but speed shouldn't be the only concern ;)

Answer (score 0):

Solution I have found for illustative purpose.

Very similar to Mozway one but not taking into account the SAM / SAMANTHA problem exposed.

```py
import pandas as pd

fct = pd.DataFrame({'NUMBIL':[858, 863, 870, 871, 872, 880, 881],
                   'DATE':['01/01/23', '01/01/23', '01/01/23', '07/01/23', '07/01/23', '08/01/23', '08/01/23'],
                   'CONTENTS':['Billed to HENRY', 'VIKTOR', 'Regard to ALEX', 'MARK 01*', 
                               'To charge SAMANTHA every Thursday', 'VIKTOR LECOMTE', '****'],
                   'AMOUNT':['25$', '96$', '13$', '96$', '96$', '13$', '13$'],
                   })

cust = pd.DataFrame({'CUSTOMERS':['VIKTOR', 'ALEX', 'SAMANTHA'],
                   })

m = fct['CONTENTS'].str.contains('|'.join(cust['CUSTOMERS']))
r = fct[~m]

print(r)
```

```
   NUMBIL      DATE         CONTENTS AMOUNT
0     858  01/01/23  Billed to HENRY    25$
3     871  07/01/23         MARK 01*    96$
6     881  08/01/23             ****    13$
```